# 1000baseT/Full Supported and Advertised but not working!

Tags: networking

i'm using a AT3IONT-I motherboard with integrated card. If I ethtool it to 1000 full duplex it wont work!
Here is sudo ethtool eth0:

```
 Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
    Link detected: yes
```

here is sudo lshw -C network:

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: bc:ae:c5:8b:7d:33
       size: 100MB/s
       capacity: 1GB/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.021.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100MB/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:f8fff000-f8ffffff memory:f8ff8000-f8ffbfff memory:fbff0000-fbffffff
```

And lspci -nn:

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 Host Bridge [10de:0a82] (rev b1)
00:00.1 RAM memory [0500]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0a88] (rev b1)
00:03.0 ISA bridge [0601]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 LPC Bridge [10de:0aad] (rev b3)
00:03.1 RAM memory [0500]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0aa4] (rev b1)
00:03.2 SMBus [0c05]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 SMBus [10de:0aa2] (rev b1)
00:03.3 RAM memory [0500]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0a89] (rev b1)
00:03.5 Co-processor [0b40]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 Co-processor [10de:0aa3] (rev b1)
00:04.0 USB Controller [0c03]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller [10de:0aa5] (rev b1)
00:04.1 USB Controller [0c03]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller [10de:0aa6] (rev b1)
00:06.0 USB Controller [0c03]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller [10de:0aa7] (rev b1)
00:06.1 USB Controller [0c03]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller [10de:0aa9] (rev b1)
00:08.0 Audio device [0403]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio [10de:0ac0] (rev b1)
00:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 PCI Bridge [10de:0aab] (rev b1)
00:0b.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 RAID Controller [10de:0abc] (rev b1)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0ac4] (rev b1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0aa0] (rev b1)
00:15.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0ac6] (rev b1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation ION VGA [10de:087d] (rev b1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
```

If i use

Code:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0  speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off
```

then in ethtool speed is Unknown and it doesn't work; if I set it via pre-up it wont work either...

Please help!!

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of switch?  Perhaps it doesn't support autonegotiate?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know (based on your comments below) that the frequency bandwidth of regular cat5e is more than enough to support gigabit and even 10gigabit ethernet (when that comes around), no reason to spend more on cat6 for a while

Answer (score 5):

Your switch needs to support gigabit as well, and you need to be using cat5e cable.

Comment: Hello! The problem was the brand new cat6 cable!! It was malfunctional and as I replaced it everything went fine.. 

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to have both, your network adapter in your PC (Your NIC) AND your switch or router support 1000Base. If both devices do not support 1000Base then they will lower themselves to the maximum supported. For example if you have a router that supports 10/100/1000 but a network card that supports 10/100, you will connect to the maximum supported between both devices which is 100.

If you have 10/100/1000 on your PC Network Card BUT have a router or switch that only supports 10/100 then you will only connect at the maximum of 100.

Worst case scenario would be a switch that supports 10 only and you have a 10/100/1000 network card. Your maximum in this case would be 10 since it is the only one that both devices can talk to each other.

Please verify your switch/router maximum connection and let us know.

Comment: Thanks, but all cables and switches support Gigabit Ethernet. When on the device it was installed Windows 7 the network adapter worked properly! If I can't get it working in Ubuntu I'll be going back to it :(...

Comment: If you are 100% that the switch is Gigalan then make sure two more things which are sometimes the problem: 1. Make sure the port you connected the cable is in fact gigalan compatible since some devices come with a group that support 1000 and another group that supports 10/100. 2. Make sure the cable is well made. What i mean is that the rj45 cable looks ok and tests ok, the connectors of the cable are ok. In some cases, the cable has a problem (Maybe twisted too many times) and it creates problems. Let me know how it went.

Comment: Hello! The problem was the brand new cat6 cable!! It was malfunctional and as I replaced it everything went fine.. 

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: No problem even though the real problem was not related to ubuntu. At least you learned more today.